# What is the purpose of @next/react-dev-overlay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a NextJs project. In it, I have found this piece of code inside `next.config.js`:

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
    'some package',
    'some package',
    'emittery',
    '@next/react-dev-overlay'
]);
```

I was wondering what is the purpose of this `@next/react-dev-overlay` and was not able to find anything online. The only thing was [this unanswered question](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/21601) in the nextjs github issues. When I remove it, it seems that the project is working as expected. My question is what is the purpose of this @next/react-dev-overlay package and should I remove it?

Comment: Not sure but I guess it has something to do with Development Errors.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@next/react-dev-overlay`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/react-dev-overlay) package is a development-only overlay for React apps. It's used internally by Next.js to display the error messages you see in development.

This is what the error overlay looks like when a client-side error occurs in a Next.js app:

[image: error overlay from @next/react-dev-overlay]

---

As to why that package was included in `next.config.js`, I can only guess that it's being used directly in that app, and needs to be transpiled to be used. Most of the times you wouldn't need to install it or use it directly.